# Adding Service Reference address in Workflow Service

Tags: c#, wcf, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflowservice

I have tried to google up the problem I'm having with a workflow service sample and to solve it to no avail. I've contacted the author, but have not heard from him.

The downloaded sample, https://github.com/PeteGoo/Workflow.EmailApprovalSample, works great. While trying to replicate it for my own project, I stumbled on Adding Service Reference in the Console application named ApproverClient.

The solution in the sample consists of three projects:

1. A WCF Workflow Service Application named ApprovalWorkflow. It comes with Service1.xamlx, which is, I assume, renamed to Workflow.xamlx.
2. An MVC named Approval.Web. A Service Reference is added and has this address http//:

   > > localhost:1708/Workflow.xamlx
3. A Console Application named ApproverClient. A Service Reference is added and has this address http//:

   > > localhost:1358/Service1.xamlx

The web.config and the app.config contain the same endpoint address http//:

> > localhost:1708/Workflow.xamlx

My question is:  Where does the Service Reference address in ApproverClient come from? There is no Service1.xamlx in any of the three projects.

I'd appreciate your help. If you know similar code samples, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the service reference and add it again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured it after some trials and errors. I've marked your answer as accepted.